# Testing if Adobe components are installed on the system

Tags: windows, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Does anyone know how to test if a given Adobe component (Illustrator, or Photoshop, whatever) is installed on a system (Windows7). Probably this would be a variable stored in a registry, but what exact key would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed those, you can check out yourself: using `regedit`, in a command-console (Start->Run->"regedit").

It might be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\`. Since I've only installed Acrobat Reader (which is also an Adobe component), it was at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader`. You can, perhaps, also get a version number, by checking for the following key. For Adobe Reader it was: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\8.0`